# Hardware interpretation in verilog for blocking assignments

Tags: verilog

Does hardware interpret both verilog codes in the same way?

non-blocking code:

```
module nonblock (input logic clock);   
logic a, b, c;

always @(posedge clock)  
begin 
   a <= b;  
   b <= c;
end  
endmodule
```

blocking code:

```
module block (input logic clock);   
logic a, b, c;

always @(posedge clock)  
begin 
   a = b;  
   b = c;
end  
endmodule
```

Comment: in this case you will probably get the same hardware because the result of the model you've described with your verilog is the same in both cases.  In HDLs you describe a kind of ideal model of what should happen - you are not telling the synthesizer to 'make hardware like this', you are saying 'make hardware that behaves like my model'.   If you flip the order of a=b; b=c; then you will get different behaviour from each hardware description and therefore different hardware

Answer (score -1):

They will not synthesize the same way.  The code that uses the blocking assignments will create two Flip-Flops in a row.  The code that uses the non-blocking assignments will just assign a to c in one clock cycle.  You can verify this in simulation.

Here's more information on [Blocking vs. Nonblocking in Verilog](http://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html)

Comment: "...will just assign a to c in one clock..." it's not. It would, if assignments order was b=c; a=b;